# Get SDL2 Mouse Position

Tags: c++, sdl-2

How would I get the position of the mouse in c++ SDL2? I found this wiki however I'm not really sure what it means and how would I get the x and y in int form?
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetMouseState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function described at the link you found; with pointers to the two `int` variables which you want to receive the coordinates.

Simplified, the function works like this one:

```
void SetXto5(int* x)
{*x = 5;}
```

i.e. the variable which your parameter points to will receive a value.
(This skips the check for NULL pointer, which is implied in the documentation.)

This does of course require the SDL environment to be correctly set up and initialised. I assume from your comments that you do not ask about that background part.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
int x, y;
Uint32 buttons = SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
```